# How to set default value inside mock unit test for class property?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit, moq

```
public MyClass 
{
    bool myflag ;
    bool detail ;
}

private async Task DemoAsync()
{
    MyClass myclassobj = new();
}
```

But in test case I want to set default value for `myflag` and `detail` as `true` using mock I'm trying like below but getting error.

```
[TestMethod()]
public async Task Demotest()
{        
    bool someProperty = true;
    var mock = new Mock<MyClass>();
    mock.SetupSet(m => m.myflag = It.IsAny<bool>())
        .Callback<bool>(p => someProperty = p)
        .Verifiable();   
}
```

Error:

> Error - Unsupported expression: m => m... The next member after the last one shown above is non-virtual, sealed, or not visible to the proxy factory.

Comment: You can't mock a field. You should use properties. You also need to make them overridable using `virtual`.

Comment: i tried even if doing virtual when code comes here ` MyClass myclassobj = new();` after unit test case run its again set it to false. kindly give me code snippet if mine is wrong

Comment: If you're manually instantiating a new `MyClass` in your method to test, you can't mock it at all, because it will be a separate instance. You need to inject the `MyClass`, which will allow you to use your mock.

Comment: oh ok thank you could you pls help me with code sample

Comment: It seems that mocking isn't the appropriate way to test this. Is there any other way to check that `myclassobj.myflag` has been set correctly? Can you share your whole method?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the **myflag** and **detail** properties virtual.
This allows for the values to be overridden.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public virtual bool myflag { get; set; }
    public virtual bool detail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i tried even if doing virtual when code comes here ` MyClass myclassobj = new();` after unit test case run its again set it to false. kindly give me code snippet if mine is wrong

Comment: Can you try to change mock.SetupSet to mock.SetupProperty and see if it helps?